# ASP.NET MVC View inside view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and I would like to ask how to make "cascading" view (I don't know if this is the correct term).

Let's see: I have a view that returns car brands, let's say in http://localhost/brand.

If I go to `http://localhost/brand/1`, I get the details of the brand with code 1

I can create another view with the models of each brand, let's say `http://localhost/models` and `http://localhost/models/2` I get the model details

But what I want is to go to `http://localhost/car/1/2` and get the some details of that model. But must be a relation between brand and model

In ASP.NET MVC, how can I get this view inside the view ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The term you're looking for is *Partial View*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is setting up some *partial views* and use it when rendering the details of a car.

### What is a *partial view*?

It's a view inside view. You can have multiple *partial views* in a view file.

### How to use?

```cs
@Html.Partial("{your view name}", "{your model}")
```

So back to your example: you want to show some information related to `brand` and `model`  when rendering the details of a `car`.

Assuming that:

- the view model for `http://localhost/brands/1` is `CarBrandViewModel` and
- the view model for `http://localhost/models/2` is `CarModelViewModel`.

#### Model

For your `car` detail page, you need to define a `CarDetailViewModel`:

```cs
public class CarViewModel
{
    public CarBrandViewModel CarBrand { get; set; }
    public CarModelViewModel CarModel { get; set; }
    /* some other fields for your car */
}
```

And this `CarViewModel` will be the view model of `http://localhost/car/1/2`.

#### View

You need to define 3 view files:

- the view file for car's detail e.g. `CarDetail.cshtml`;
- the *partial view* for brand info e.g `Shared\_CarBrandDetail.cshtml`;
- the *partial view* for model info e.g. `Shared\_CarModelDetail.cshtml`

The `_CarBrandDetail.cshtml` file should accepts a `CarBrandViewModel` object as the model:

```cs
// in your _CarBrandDetail.cshtml...
@model CarBrandViewModel

<!-- your code for rendering brand information ->
```

Define the similar thing in `_CarModelDetail.cshtml`. This time you should set:

```cs
@model CarModelViewModel
```

Now, in `CarDetail.cshtml`:

```cs
// in your CarDetail.cshtml...
@model CarViewModel

@* render your brand's details *@
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("_CarBrandDetail", Model.CarBrand);
}

@* render your model's details *@
@{
    Html.RenderPartial("_CarModelDetail", Model.CarModel);
}

<!-- your code for rendering other details of the car -->
```

#### Note:

- A `@{` `}` pair is required to surround the `Html.RenderPartial();` call.
- It's not necessary to put all the partial views under `Shared` folder. However, if you put the partial views somewhere else under `Views`, you need to change the file path when calling `Html.RenderPartial()`.
- You may want to reuse your `_CarBrandDetail` in `http://localhost/brands/1`. In this case you can make a view for the `brand/{id}` page and then call the `_CarBrandDetail` partial view.